# Magento 2 : style-m.css and style-l.css is not appearing in frontend

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1.3

I am facing a weird issue with magento 2.1.3. style-m.css and style-l.css is not appering in frontend. Due to this frontend designs are messing up. I have tried following command to fix this issue but unable to get resolution.

1. `php -f bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`
2. `php -f bin/magento indexer:reindex`
3. `php -f bin/magento cache:flush`

**Mode : Development**

**Cache Status : Disable**

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have this same problem now. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Have you removed pub/static/.htaccess file. If yes then copy from magento2.

Make sure 0777 permission to pub/static

Comment: I did that but issue still persist.

Comment: I have updated the question, Have a look again.

Comment: 777? That's too open

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
sudo rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/frontend/*
```

Comment: I did that but issue persist.. I have updated the question with screenshot.